# Referencing another schema in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

if I have two schemas like:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    twittername: String,
    twitterID: Number,
    displayName: String,
    profilePic: String,
});

var  User = mongoose.model('User') 

var postSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    postedBy: User,  //User Model Type
    dateCreated: Date,
    comments: [{body:"string", by: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId}],
});
```

I tried to connect them together like the example above but I couldn't figure out how to do it. Eventually, if I can do something like this it would make my life very easy

```
var profilePic = Post.postedBy.profilePic
```

Answer (score 261, accepted):

It sounds like the populate method is what your looking for. First make small change to your post schema:

```
var postSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    postedBy: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    dateCreated: Date,
    comments: [{body:"string", by: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId}],
});
```

Then make your model:

```
var Post = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);
```

Then, when you make your query, you can populate references like this:

```
Post.findOne({_id: 123})
.populate('postedBy')
.exec(function(err, post) {
    // do stuff with post
});
```

Comment: What is the "ref" field for? I can't find documentation on it.

Comment: @KarlMorrison ref field means in which collection the id mentioned is going to be searched for.

Comment: what would be the difference between populate and addToSet?

Comment: where is reference for `by:` selectro

Comment: @KarlMorrison The docs for "ref" are buried in the docs for `populate`: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: This is how i do it but the output is always an ObjectId instead of the Object's json properties.

Answer (score 30):

Addendum: No one mentioned "Populate" --- it is very much worth your time and money looking at Mongooses Populate Method : Also explains cross documents referencing

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Answer (score 17):

Late reply, but adding that Mongoose also has the concept of [Subdocuments](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html)

With this syntax, you should be able to reference your `userSchema` as a type in your `postSchema` like so:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    twittername: String,
    twitterID: Number,
    displayName: String,
    profilePic: String,
});

var postSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    postedBy: userSchema,
    dateCreated: Date,
    comments: [{body:"string", by: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId}],
});
```

Note the updated `postedBy` field with type `userSchema`.

This will embed the user object within the post, saving an extra lookup required by using a reference. Sometimes this could be preferable, other times the ref/populate route might be the way to go. Depends on what your application is doing.

Comment: For any reason, if you want to avoid '_id' field in the 'Other' schema, add below field to Other schema and mongoose will omit it. _id: { type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId, value: null }

Answer (score 3):

This is in addition to D. Lowe's answer which worked for me but needed a bit of tweaking. (I would have put this as a comment but I don't have the reputation to do so, and I would like to see this information in a few months when I encounter this issue again but I forget how to solve it.)

If you are importing a Schema from another file, then you will need to add .schema to the end of the import.

Note: I am unsure if you get the Invalid schema configuration if you are not importing schemas and using local schemas instead but importing is just cleaner and easier to handle for me.

For example:

```
// ./models/other.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const otherSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    content:String,
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Other', otherSchema)

//*******************SEPERATE FILES*************************//

// ./models/master.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

//You will get the error "Invalid schema configuration: `model` is not a valid type" if you omit .schema at the end of the import
const Other=require('./other').schema


const masterSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    others:[Other],
    singleOther:Other,
    otherInObjectArray:[{
        count:Number,
        other:Other,
    }],
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Master', masterSchema);
```

Then, wherever you use this (for me I used code similar to this in my Node.js API) you can simply assign other to master.

For example:

```
const Master= require('../models/master')
const Other=require('../models/other')

router.get('/generate-new-master', async (req, res)=>{
    //load all others
    const others=await Other.find()

    //generate a new master from your others
    const master=new Master({
        others,
        singleOther:others[0],
        otherInObjectArray:[
            {
                count:1,
                other:others[1],
            },
            {
                count:5,
                other:others[5],            
            },
        ],
    })

    await master.save()
    res.json(master)
})
```

Comment: Do you have documentation for this post? Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, this was an excerpt from my own works and I haven't thought of it for over a year. MongoDB does have free classes that you can enjoy at https://learn.mongodb.com/

Comment: For any reason, if you want to avoid '_id' field in the 'Other' schema, add below field to Other schema and mongoose will omit it.



  _id: { type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId, value: null }

Answer (score 1):

```js
{body: "string", by: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId}
```

The `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId` will create a new id, try changing it to more direct type, like String or Number.