# Using ObjectId with Mongoose in MongoDB

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

I have recently begun using MongoDB with Mongoose and have what probably seems like a straightforward question.
I have two models so far, a User and a post. Posts are owned by a user, this is referenced by the ObjectId.
Here are the models:

**Post**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

  text: String,
  stars: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  score: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', default: '554cb70669234d6f04f425a2' }
});

PostSchema.methods.addstar = function(cb) {
  this.stars += 1;
  this.save(cb);
};

mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
```

**User**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {type: String, lowercase: true, unique: true},
  hash: String,
  salt: String
});

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

When I want to use the data on the HTML page with angular I am trying to access the username by using:

`{{ post.user.username }}`

However this isn't yielding any results. 
Do I need to make a separate get request with the userid, or is their a more intuitive way?

As mentioned, I understand this question may seem quite basic. I am just learning Mongo, and have previously worked with Rails Databases, where a lot of functionality is obscured.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code returns all of the posts with the users populated for each one. I had forgotten to include the empty object inside the method call for Post.find().

```
router.get('/posts', function (req, res, next) {
  Post.find({})
  .populate('user')
  .exec(function (err, posts) {
    if(err){ return(err); }
    res.json(posts);
  });
});
```

Comment: Great! Indeed my answer targeted the findOne method, but it is the same for other finds.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the answer is in here:
[Referencing another schema in Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18001478/referencing-another-schema-in-mongoose)

Summary:

when you make your query, you can populate references like this:

```
Post.findOne({_id: 123})
.populate('user')
.exec(function(err, post) {
    // do stuff with post
});
```

So before you execute the find, you tell mongo to populate the user.

Comment: Thank you @tuvokki. Thats works for one post. In my initial get request I'm getting all of the posts and want to populate each ones username. This code isn't working: `Post.find()
  .populate('user', 'username')
  .exec(function (err, posts) {
    if(err){ return(err); }
    res.json(posts);
  });`