# MongoDB object type/nested schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Okay so I have an events.js file with an eventSchema:

```
var eventSchema = mongoose.Schema({
name:{
    type: String,
    //required: true
venue:{

}
});
```

and a venue.js with the venue schema:

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

```
var venueSchema = mongoose.Schema(
{
name:{
    type: String,
    //required: true
},
postcode:{
    type: String,
    //required: true
},
town:{
    type: String,
    //required: true
}
});
```

My question is how can I have the 'venue' field in the events schema be linked to the venue schema. So essentially when you create a new event you can only add a venue from the list of venues. Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18001478/referencing-another-schema-in-mongoose

Answer (score 1):

You can link it by id.
You don't have to add all 'venue' field in the events schema.

```
var eventSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name:{
    type: String,
    //required: true
  },
  venue_id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
});
```

Since you're using Mongoose, You can make field like,

```
venue_id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Venue' }
```

which uses [populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) method.

Population is the process of automatically replacing the **specified paths**(which is venue_id) in the document with **document(s) from other collection(s)** (which is document matched with venue_id).

You can use it like

```
event.
  findOne({ name: 'somename' }).
  populate('venue').
  exec(function (err, event) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
});
```

It will return event doc with venue doc that match with venue_id, not just venue_id.

Comment: is this the correct syntax?  venue:{ 
 venue_id: {
  type: Schema.Types.ObjectId
 }
 }

Comment: venue:{ venue_id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId } } is not the correct syntax. What you want to do is make reference of venue schema. You can make venue_id field which holds venue collection's id like my answer. Or if you want to make more specific, create field like venue_id: {{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Venue'}.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more how the populate method works? How should I use it in this instance. Thanks!!

Comment: Thank you. How does this work in relation to POST requests, i.e. can I simply do POST: {"name":"eventName", {venue:"venue_id"}} and it will return the venue? Cheers!

Comment: Are you asking about inserting doc ? You don't have to wrap venue field in bracket. Just {name: "eventName", venue_id: "venue_id}

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by @godsnam is correct but when you want to use references in your schema. If you don't want to do it using references then this might help you.

You can do link your venueSchema in eventSchema by simply writing as below.

```
var venueSchema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name: {
            type: String,
            //required: true
        },
        postcode: {
            type: String,
            //required: true
        },
        town: {
            type: String,
            //required: true
        }
    });

var eventSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        //required: true
    },
    venue: venueSchema
});
```

Comment: How do I do this given that the venueSchema is in another file (in the same folder)?

Comment: You can do require(schemaPath);

Comment: Okay so i've done: Venue = require('./venues'); in the events.js file and then in the eventSchema i've added: venue: venueSchema but in the terminal I get referenceError: venueSchema is not defined :/

Comment: Do venueSchema = require(). And inside venueSchema file do module.exports = your venueSchema

Comment: Thanks a lot! that seems to work! Although do you know why when I do a GET request on the events the venue name becomes really weird, like this:    "0": "0",
   "1": "2",
   "2": " ",
   "3": "A",
   "4": "c",
   "5": "a",
   "6": "d",
   "7": "e",
   "8": "m",
   "9": "y",
when I do a GET request on the venue it just says name:02academy

Comment: i'm still a bit confused - how do you refer to the venue when you make a POST request - how do you fill it in "venue":"<what goes here>"

Comment: Complete object which have name, postcode and town in it.

Comment: Okay but I already have venues that I want to add to the events, rather than fill in all the venue details - is that possible?

Comment: Not getting what you are saying.

Comment: Well on my app I want to be able to add venues to events, and add events to venues. How do I code it so that I create venues separately (with all their details), then link these venues to the events without repeating the details? Cheers.

Comment: If I got you correctly then I think you should go with referencing. Here how you can do reference and populate. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: Okay so i have venue: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Venue'} and  Post.findOne({_id: })
.populate('venue')
.exec(function(err,post)){

}); what should i put in the function & the _id:?