# NestJS - Embedding Nested Document with enum using mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, enums, nestjs

I am trying to create a Schema structure like so,

```
import  *  as  mongoose  from  'mongoose';
import  *  as  Stop  from  'stop-model';
    export  const  RouteSchema  =  new  mongoose.Schema({
    _id:  String,
    stop: [Stop],
    type: { type:  String, enum: ['INBOUND', 'OUTBOUND'] }
    }, {
    versionKey:  false,
    timestamps: { createdAt:  'createTime', updatedAt:  'updateTime' }
});
```

Where stop model is an Interface,

```
import { Document } from  'mongoose';
export  interface  Stop  extends  Document {
    _id:  String,
    stopName:  String,
    type:  StopType,
    createTime:  number,
    updateTime:  number
}

export  enum  StopType {
    PARKING=  'PARKING',
    WAYPOINT  =  'WAYPOINT',
    STOP  =  'STOP'
}
```

However when running I get the error below

> TypeError: Undefined type `PARKING` at `StopType.PARKING`   Did you
>   try nesting Schemas? You can only nest using refs or arrays.

My goal is to have list of  `Stops` in the `Routes` collection.

I also have a `StopSchema` defined like so,

```
import  *  as  mongoose  from  'mongoose';

export  const  StopSchema  =  new  mongoose.Schema({
    _id:  String,
    stopName:  String,
    type: { type:  String, enum: ['PARKING', 'WAYPOINT', 'STOP'] }
    }, {
    versionKey:  false,
    timestamps: { createdAt:  'createTime', updatedAt:  'updateTime' }
});
```

I am not sure how to use `StopSchema` as a ref inside `RouteSchema`. (Something on the lines of this answer [Referencing another schema in Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18001478/referencing-another-schema-in-mongoose), but in a NestJS way).

Answer (score 2):

In mongoose, to refer other schemas within a schema, you have to use `Schema.Types.ObjectId`.
So in your case, the code would look like this:

```
import  *  as  mongoose  from  'mongoose';

export  const  RouteSchema  =  new  mongoose.Schema({
    _id:  String,
    stop: { type: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: false }] },
    type: { type:  String, enum: ['INBOUND', 'OUTBOUND'] }
    }, {
    versionKey:  false,
    timestamps: { createdAt:  'createTime', updatedAt:  'updateTime' }
});
```

Let me know if it helps ;)