# Node.js, MongoDB error - "message": "Schema hasn't been registered for model \"Category\".\nUse mongoose.model(name, schema)"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose-schema

I'm in process of an app based on Node.js, MongoDB and Express. My goal is to get a fetch API system to work.

When using Postman to check out my status, the GET for "article.js" model file (in my localhost:3000/articles) shows the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Schema hasn't been registered for model \"Category\".\nUse mongoose.model(name, schema)",
        "name": "MissingSchemaError"
    }
}
```

This error disables the display of my articles or categories in Postman, as they are saved in my MongoDB project area at mongodb [cloud](https://cloud.mongodb.com).
The model file code "article.js" is the following:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const articleSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    description: { type: String, required: true },
    content: { type: String, required: true },
    categoryId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'Category' }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Article', articleSchema);
```

This file connects with the controller named "articles.js", with the following relevant code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Article = require('../models/article');
const Category = require('../models/category');

module.exports = {
    getAllArticles: (req, res) => {
        Article.find().populate('categoryId', 'title').then((articles) => {    
            res.status(200).json({
                articles
            })
        }).catch(error => {
            res.status(500).json({
                error
            })        
        });
    },
    createArticle: (req, res) => {

    const { title, description, content, categoryId } = req.body;

    Category.findById(categoryId).then((category) => {
        if (!category) {
            return res.status(404).json({
                message: 'Category not found'
            })
        }

        const article = new Article({
            _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
            title,
            description,
            content,
            categoryId
        });     

        return article.save();
    }).then(() => {
        res.status(200).json({
            message: 'Created article'
        })
    }).catch(error => {
        res.status(500).json({
            error
        })        
    });    
},
}
```

The model file "category.js" code in the app looks like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const categorySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    description: { type: String, required: true }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Category', categorySchema);
```

I looked up topics from the past here, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52238703/nodejsmongoose-missingschemaerror-schema-hasnt-been-registered-for-model-ca) - but it didn't solve my problem.

What should I do in order to fix my code?

Is it a syntax mistake or something else?

Comment: Where is your code showing your Category model? You are showing the import but cannot see the code for when you are creating that model

Comment: See I added some relevant code, tell me if you understand now what's the solution.

Comment: Why are you trying to populate the 'title' field - that field is not a referenced field but is native to the article model. Try removing that

Comment: Well, I continued writing some code and now it works fine. Probably you are right, thare was no special problem in thte code itself. Anyway now it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

the code seems to be OK

I don't see here any particular error's