# How to find documents by Id from an Array of IDs taken from another schema?

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

i have 2 mongoose Schemas like this:

```
 var RecipeSchema = new Schema({
      type: String,
      version: String,
      data:  [{type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Data'}]
  });
  var Recipe = mongoose.model("Recipe", RecipeSchema);

 var DataSchema = new Schema({
     ex1: String,
     ex2: String,
     ex3: String
 });
 var Data = mongoose.model("Data", DataSchema);
```

if i am working in a function with a "selected" recipe, how can i do the Data.find() to match in the Data Schema only the Datas with the _id that i have in the data array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Referencing another schema in Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18001478/referencing-another-schema-in-mongoose)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the selected recipe is 'recipe', you can just do,

```
recipe.populate('data', function (err, recipe) {
    // here recipe.data will have the array of data objects instead of just _ids
  });
```

This won't work if the selected recipe is lean or not a mongoose document

Comment: so is this right?: 
     Recipe.findById(idR, function (err, recipe){
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err)
                    }
                    recipe.populate('data', function (err, recipe){
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err)

                        }
                        res.send({
                            datarecipe: recipe.data
                        })
                    })
        })

Comment: BTW, you can also write this I think, 
Recipe.findById(idR).
    populate('data').
    exec(function (err, recipe) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
        res.send({ datarecipe: recipe.data })
    })

Comment: I'm assuming initially recipes.data had an array of ids which are present in the _id field of the 'data' collection.

Comment: and what if i have to delete all datas in Data collection that are in the data array of the selected recipe?

Comment: You don't even need to populate for that

Data.deleteMany({ _id: { $in: recipe.data } }, function (err) {});

Answer (score 0):

Fix field type:

```
data: {
  type: [Schema.ObjectId],
  ref: 'Data',
  default: []
}
```

Usage:

```
const Recipe = mongoose.model('Recipe');

router.get('/recipes', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const recipes = await Recipe.find({}).populate('data').lean();
    res.status(200).send(recipes);
  }
  catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send({message: error.message});
  }
});
```