# Load default data from external .json-file and store into MongoDB

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb

I would like to load JSON data from external `test_data.json` file if environment variable `TEST` is set. I am able to load the JSON object, but I struggle converting it to previously created Mongoose model. My model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const SensorSchema = require('./sensor');

const DataEntrySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    datetime: { type: Date, required: true },
    sensor: { type: SensorSchema, required: true },
    value: { type: Number, required: true }
});
  
const DataEntry = mongoose.model('DataEntry', DataEntrySchema);

module.exports = DataEntry;
```

Node.js server code:

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/",{
        useCreateIndex:true,
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true}
).then(() => {
    console.log('Database Successfully Connected')
    if(fill_default_data) {

      var obj = DataEntry( JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'test_data.json'), 'utf8')) );
      obj.save();

    }
  }, error => {
    console.log(error)
  }
);
```

Content of `test_data.json`:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1337,
        "datetime": "28/08/2021 16:01",
        "sensor": {
            "id": 123,
            "type": "Temperaure"
        },
        "value": 2502
    }
]
```

But this fails with error message :

> (node:13676) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError:
> DataEntry validation failed: value: Path `value` is required., sensor:
> Path `sensor` is required., datetime: Path `datetime` is required.

Any tips how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you aren't saving an individual DataEntry entity, but trying to save a whole array of them.

Log what comes back from:

```
const items = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'test_data.json'), 'utf8'))
```

Either loop through the array and save the DataEntry items individually.  Or use the blulk load option:

```
DataEntry.create(items)...
```

with the above items.

Comment: Thank you! This `populate` also helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18001478/referencing-another-schema-in-mongoose