# Types for referencing another schema in mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to ask a question in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18001478/referencing-another-schema-in-mongoose) but I don't have the need reputation to ask. So I created this post. The question is: Is possible to referencing other schema in mongoose using another variable type? (e.g. Number, String, etc). I know you need the ref flag in specification but I don't know if mongoose is limited to reference by only using Schema.Types.ObjectId type.

Any clarification will be greatly recieved!

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, you can check this: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/lookup-does-data-type-of-join-fields-matter-from-performance-stand-point/127356/5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use types other than `ObjectId` for `ref`s, but Mongoose recommends using `ObjectId`s unless you have a good reason to do otherwise.

From the [documentation for Populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate):

> **Note**: `ObjectId`, `Number`, `String`, and `Buffer` are valid for use as refs. However, you should use `ObjectId` unless you are an advanced user and have a good reason for doing so.